# WebComponent implementation in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I see a change in writing frontend application, moving out from MVC world to web-component system. But does Angular support web component standards, can i build pure web-component using angular.

I found polymer as one of the library for this work but not able to grab anything similar in Angular. Are we planning these standard to be part of Angular in later releases or we need to glue polymer in Angular for writing framework agnostic webcomponents (as per w3c standards)

Answer (score 0):

You can't build web components with Angular.
That was an early goal but was later dropped because it didn't seem worth the effort.
You can use web-components in Angular applications though.

Comment: that means if you want to go by web-component route then you must use polymer type library. Is this a good combination considering we want to build widget library stuff (lots of dash-boarding application will re-use these widgets), any reference would be good to start on this for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Angular has components, directives, pipes, services, and modules that are reusable. You can only reuse them in Angular applications though. If you want to create something that can be used in any web application independent of the used framework, pure Polymer is probably the best option.